# Creating html table from list in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a list (from text file) to an html table code to insert in an html file. I used jinja2 succesfully to a part where I replace a keyword in html file to the html table code that I created earlier. The problem is that inside the html file all the new table tags are changed into `&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;` and it should be `<tr><td>` etc. This is the code I use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from os.path import abspath
import plistlib
from jinja2 import Template
from collections import Counter



my_plist = plistlib.readPlist("iphone_data/app_info.plist")
iphone_version = my_plist["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
changelog = open("changelog.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
list1 = changelog.readlines()
template = Template("""
    {% for item, count in bye.items() %}
         <tr><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
""")
log = template.render(bye=Counter(list1))
file = abspath('iphone_data/letter.html')
html = open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
target = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'wersja_1'))
changes = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'changelog'))
for v in target:
    v.replace_with(v.replace('wersja_1', iphone_version))
for c in changes:
    c.replace_with(c.replace('changelog', log))

html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open("iphone_data/letter_mod.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

I also replace version read from plist file but that works perfect. What should the correct code look like to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
html = soup.prettify("utf-8")
```

with

```
html = soup.prettify("utf-8", formatter=None)
```

**[More Info](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a Flask module available just for tables: "flask_table". Documentation available here: http://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, you can define the items in your table as an array or dictionary and process them in this way:

```
#load items from your database with something like
items = ItemModel.query.all()
# Populate the table
table = ItemTable(items)

# Print the html
print(table.__html__())
# or just {{ table }} from within a Jinja template
```